# Distributed Marketing Image Block

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I'm trying to create a custom distributed marketing image block as per the standard documentation *[Add a Distributed Marketing Image Block](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_dm_add_dm_image_block.htm&type=5)*

I've created a package but while adding the Custom Content Block it gives the error to the Endpoint URL,

```
https://distributed-marketing-content-blocks.{{stackKey}}.marketingcloudapps.com/image-block/v1/
```

Comment: what error are you getting and where? I was able to create an installed package with the URL you provided

Comment: Hi @EazyE, It was giving the invalid URL, But after I tried into the incognito mode it's worked for me.